# How i can scan numbers from text file from start to the EOF and store them into array?

Tags: c, arrays, text

Text txt.file is argument and has numbers:

```
154 456 22 3 22
213 312 33 4325
```

I want to scan numbers from a test.txt and store them into array.
   This scanning only first 3 numbers. I have no idea why is that so.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int c[40];
  int i=0;

  FILE *ptr;
  ptr=fopen(argv[1],"r");
  do
  {
    fscanf(ptr,"%d",&c[i]);

    i++;

  }while(c[i]!=-1);

for(int k=0;k<i;k++) printf("%d ",c[k]);    
  fclose(ptr);    
    return 0;
}
```

How i can find EOF?

Output is: 154 456 22.

Comment: *How i can find EOF?* Read the documentation of `fscanf()`.  It returns a value for a reason.

Comment: You're incrementing `i` *before* checking for `-1`, and besides it's the wrong check. You want to check the *return value* from the function.

Comment: [This effort is worth taking it](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+detect+EOF+using+scanf+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: I would place this line of code insted of your do while loop

  while(i<40 && EOF != fscanf(ptr,"%d %d %d %d %d",&c[i++],&c[i++],&c[i++],&c[i++],&c[i++])) ;